# How to spell check code and markdown within Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

When I'm writing Markdown files outside of VSC I use Grammarly for spell checking. I've found the extension [Grammarly (unofficial)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=znck.grammarly) but it doesn't work.

How do you spell check your code (comments, messages in dialog boxes, .md files, etc.)?

Comment: Looks like Grammarly extension works again

Answer (score 70, accepted):

After testing a few of the extensions I've decided to use [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker). It has a super useful shortcut `CTRL+.` that shows suggestions for spelling.

Comment: It's a nice solution but this extension has been disabled when using virtual workspaces.

Comment: Would be nice to have an O365 Grammar check API so we could send markdown or C# comments from the editor of our choice to MS so they can be grammar checked. I'm horrible at grammar. Some organizations have approved *online* O365 for processing of sensitive information, but have not yet approved services like Grammarly, ChatGPT and Language Tool. From my experience BTW, the free version of Language Tool isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: Spell checking is nice, and can be managed within a coding IDE, but I don't believe that grammar can be.  There are so few instances where full sentences with actual grammar occur, that I feel there would be 9 false positives for every 1 useful signal.  If you're using VS Code primarily for Markdown and other text-based files, then probably VS Code isn't even the right tool.

Comment: is it possible to select the next misspelt word with a shortcut or to navigate automatically to the next misspelt word?

Comment: I also find spell-checking in a code-editor has too many false-positives. Markdown files are a different case. Keeping my personal website in Markdown, so doing a fair amount of writing where spell-check is more useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Spell Right](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ban.spellright) seems to be pretty good for prose and LaTeX, and is multilingual.